# Incorrect syntax near ')' calling stored procedure with GETDATE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, getdate

Maybe I am having a moment of 'afternoon', but can anyone explain why I get

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

When running

```
CREATE PROC DisplayDate 
    (@DateVar DATETIME) 
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT @DateVar
END
GO

EXEC DisplayDate GETDATE();
```

Answer (score 213, accepted):

You can't pass in a function call as an argument to your stored procedure. Instead use an intermediate variable:

```
DECLARE @tmp DATETIME
SET @tmp = GETDATE()

EXEC DisplayDate @tmp;
```

Comment: Is there a reason for this restriction?

Comment: @student  Is there a reason for basic restrictions like lack of boolean and integer column types or lack of filtered keys in Oracle...?

Answer (score 27):

As **Mitch Wheat** mentioned you can't pass a function.

If in your case you should pass in a precalculated value or GETDATE() - you can use default value. For example, modify your stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROC DisplayDate 
(
    @DateVar DATETIME = NULL
) AS 
BEGIN
    set @DateVar=ISNULL(@DateVar,GETDATE())

    --the SP stuff here
    SELECT @DateVar
END
GO
```

And then try:

```
EXEC DisplayDate '2013-02-01 00:00:00.000'
EXEC DisplayDate
```

**Remark**: Here I supposed that NULL value is not in use for this parameter. If it is not your case - you can use another unused value, for example '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'

Answer (score 0):

the solution I found was to declare temp variables before executing and pass these into the execution line e.g.

```
Declare @ddate date

set ddate = getdate()

EXEC DisplayDate @ddate;
```