# Procedure call with date attribute gives error

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

I have a stored procedure with attributes like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [sp_INUSAV_BASE](     
, @dUSAV_DAT DATETIME = NULL
, @dUSAV_DFR DATETIME = NULL
, @dUSAV_DTO DATETIME = NULL
```

I am trying to call this procedure from SSMS with:

```
exec sp_inusav_base @dUSAV_DAT = getdate()
```

Which is giving me error:

[image]

Why is that error? I've also tried to call like this:

```
exec sp_inusav_base  @dUSAV_DAT = (SELECT getdate())
```

But this is also giving me error:[image]

Why is that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incorrect syntax near ')' calling storedproc with GETDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399104/incorrect-syntax-near-calling-storedproc-with-getdate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a function call as a parameter for a stored procedure. You need to assign getdate() to a variable first..

Duplicate of: [Incorrect syntax near ')' calling storedproc with GETDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399104/incorrect-syntax-near-calling-storedproc-with-getdate)