# SQL Trying to use DATEADD in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, azure, datetime, stored-procedures

I've created a stored procedure in my example database on Azure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SalesLT.InsertOrderHeader(@OrderDate AS DATETIME=NULL, @DueDate AS DATETIME=NULL, @CustomerID AS INT=NULL)
AS
DECLARE @SalesOrderID INT = NEXT VALUE FOR SalesLT.SalesOrderNumber
IF @OrderDate IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @OrderDate = GETDATE()
    END

INSERT INTO SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader(SalesOrderID,OrderDate,DueDate,CustomerID,ShipMethod)
VALUES (@SalesOrderID,@OrderDate,@DueDate,@CustomerID,'CARGO TRANSPORT 5')

PRINT @SalesOrderID
```

This created fine but when I tried to call it I wanted a date a week from now:

```
EXEC SalesLT.InsertOrderHeader @DueDate= DATEADD(dd,7,getDate()) , @CustomerID=1
```

This didn't work. The errors say that where it says 'dd' it was expecting ( or select, and the same for the closing bracket of get date. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incorrect syntax near ')' calling storedproc with GETDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399104/incorrect-syntax-near-calling-storedproc-with-getdate)

Comment: You can't pass in a function call as an argument to your stored procedure. Instead use an intermediate variable
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399104/incorrect-syntax-near-calling-storedproc-with-getdate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`EXEC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql):

```
    [ [ @parameter = ] { value   
                       | @variable [ OUTPUT ]   
                       | [ DEFAULT ]   
                       }  
    ]  
  [ ,...n ]
```

Note, carefully, that it accepts *values* and it accepts *variables*. What it doesn't accept is *expressions*.

You need to move the `DATEADD` logic to a separate line and store the resulting value in a variable.

```
DECLARE @dt datetime
SET @dt = DATEADD(day,7,getDate())
EXEC SalesLT.InsertOrderHeader @DueDate= @dt , @CustomerID=1
```